# Webpack-dev-server live reload not working

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I know this question gets asked a million times but I've been through plenty of other answers and still can't seem to find a solution.

Put simply, my webpack live browser reload doesn't work, so every time I make a change I have to manually hit refresh in the browser.

Can anyone help?

Just to be clear, it's just browser reloading that I need - I don't need Hot Module Replacement at this stage.

Here's my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");

const isDevelopment = process.env.NOD_ENV !== "production";

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/app.js"),
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist")
    },
    target: "node",
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    devtool: isDevelopment && "source-map",
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        open: true,
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "./src"),
        watchContentBase: true,
        liveReload: true,
        inline: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: {
                    loader: "html-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "postcss-loader",
                        options: {
                            autoprefixer: {
                                browsers: ["last 2 versions"]
                            },
                            sourceMap: true,
                            plugins: () => [autoprefixer]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|mp4)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "file-loader",
                        options: {
                            name: "[name].[ext]",
                            outputPath: "static/",
                            useRelativePath: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "image-webpack-loader",
                        options: {
                            mozjpeg: {
                                progressive: true,
                                quality: 65
                            },
                            optipng: {
                                enabled: true
                            },
                            pngquant: {
                                quality: "65-90",
                                speed: 4
                            },
                            gifsicle: {
                                interlaced: false
                            },
                            webp: {
                                quality: 75
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name]-styles.css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: true,
            hash: true,
            template: "./src/index.html",
            filename: "index.html"
        })
    ]
};
```

And my file structure, if it helps

[image: File Structure]

Comment: Which version of webpack-dev-server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

for webpack 5 you need to add `static` object and be put in `devServer` object

```
devServer: {
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
    },
  },
```